# What's a good method to output (print) through html/servlet?

Tags: validation, servlets, message

There are certain times where I have to output html code for errors/information e.g. "Password successfully updated" or "Login failed". When I use out.println, the message is just displayed at the top of the screen, how can I perhaps use a dialog box or position this text appropriately?

```
out.println("Employee Account Successfully Created");
                 RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("NewEmployee.html"); 
                 rs.include(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would to use jsp files in the request dispatcher, and `request.setAttribute` in the servlet.

For example, you might have something like:

```
request.setAttribute("result", "Employee Account Successfully Created");
RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("NewEmployee.jsp"); 
rs.forward(request, response);
```

Then in the JSP file:

```
<html>
<!- ...Some content /->

${result}

<!- ...Some more content /->
</html>
```

Comment: Could I perhaps use a dialogbox?

Comment: Yes, `${result}` is evaluated into the String before the page is displayed, so if you're using a jquery dialogbox for example, you'd just put `${result}` in place of text in the dialog's div.

Comment: but i'm not using JSP file.

Comment: HTML files are static, so the other option would be to use ajax and have a servlet that just returns some json data you can display in a dialogbox.